# Most efficient way to get status from child table

Tags: sql

We have records (Table1), who have a workflow (submitted, approved, etc.) that occurs through inserting records in a child table (Table2). For example if the record in Table1 is submitted, a corresponding record in Table2 is inserted that has the workflow status (StatusField), date, and person submitting. When I then try to query Table1 based on its status (e.g. only submitted records), I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way and am unsure. I've tried creating functions where the PK of Table1 is the parameter and then it kicks out the most recent Statusfield from Table2 with a matching FK. I've also tried making a View with the PK of Table2 for the Max PK grouped by FK and then linked via LEFT OUTER JOIN (as there may be no corresponding records in Table2, meaning the status is pending). The way that seems faster is to do a subquery like so:

```
SELECT a.*
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 StatusField 
       FROM Table2 b
       WHERE b.FK=a.PK
       ORDER BY b.DateField DESC) StatusField
FROM Table1 a
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 StatusField 
       FROM Table2 b
       WHERE b.FK=a.PK
       ORDER BY b.DateField DESC)='Submitted'
```

I still feel like there is a better way. Any thoughts? If there is a similar question and answer someone can point me to, that would also be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution (question is tagged MySQL) - use a derived table to obtain the maximum datefield for each fk, then join back to table2 to see if statusfield is submitted....

```
select a.*
     , b.StatusField
  from table1 a
  join (select fk
             , max(datefield) datefield
          from table2
         group by fk) max on (max.fk = a.fk)
  join table2 b on (b.fk = a.fk and b.datefield = max.datefield) and b.StatusField = 'Submitted');
```

Comment: This works, not sure how much faster it is yet, but will test soon. Thank you for such a quick response!

Comment: One possible way to speed it up... make the derived table max a physical table and index it.  This will speed up the join to table1 and allows table2 to be joined directly to the max results through indexes (fk, datefield).   Good luck!